# What is this MIME type 'video/3gpp; codecs=avc1.42E00C, mp4a.40.2"'?

Tags: video-streaming, mime-types, codec, mpeg

I have to process these mime type string.

For "avc1.42E00C", I guess 'avc1' means H.264 codec and '42E00C' specify codec version or profile ?

Where can I found reliable information?

If full specification/list are hard to obtain, only 'avc1' and 'mp4a' related information would be very helpful

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363167/html5-video-tag-codecs-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Levels
For "reliablie information" check the references. Probably you have to dig through the ITU

Basically what you are looking at is this:

42 is the baseline profile (im not sure but i have never seen another number here for H264)

80 is the constrains set. (its complicated and i dont really understand it, but its go to do wtih compression methods, etc). I "think" that packetization mode = 1 might activate these parameters. But im not certain.

0C is the Level. You convert it to decimal (ie; C = 12) and then devide by 10 to get the leve. ie. the level is 1.2, then look it up in the link provided to get all the info about the H264 quality.

Thats the full extent of my knowledge on this one, as of today.