Parsing and decoding socket stream to create HTML video&audio
I have a socket stream constantly sending me partial Binary data such as shown in image below:

When I console.log() the next data chunk it appears as something as base64 as sample below:
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

When I parse this data with atob() it returns a chunk string always starts with dmoof mfhd prefix which I believe it's something about MP4 encoding.

What I also know about this data has vc: h264 ac: aac encoding and avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2 codecs in order for me to decode it.
I've tried multiple methods including hls.js, jmuxer (https://github.com/samirkumardas/jmuxer) MediaSource() but couldn't be successful to create video&audio stream in my HTML page.
This code below is the most closest try I got,
<video id="video" controls autoplay></video>
<script>
    // Convert base64 string to ArrayBuffer
    function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
      const binaryString = atob(base64);
      const bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryString.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < binaryString.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      return bytes.buffer;
    }

    class VideoStreamHandler {
      constructor() {
        this.mediaSource = null;
        this.sourceBuffer = null;
        this.videoElement = document.getElementById('video');
        this.queue = [];
        this.isInitialized = false;

        // Bind methods to maintain correct context
        this.onSourceOpen = this.onSourceOpen.bind(this);
        this.processQueue = this.processQueue.bind(this);
      }

      init() {
        this.mediaSource = new MediaSource();
        this.videoElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.mediaSource);
        this.mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', this.onSourceOpen, false);
      }

      onSourceOpen() {
        try {
          // Use a more generic codec string
          this.sourceBuffer = this.mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"');
          
          // Add event listeners to handle buffer updates
          this.sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', this.processQueue);
          
          this.isInitialized = true;
          this.processQueue();
        } catch (e) {
          console.error('Error creating SourceBuffer:', e);
        }
      }

      processQueue() {
        if (this.queue.length > 0 && !this.sourceBuffer.updating) {
          const arrayBuffer = this.queue.shift();
          try {
            this.sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(arrayBuffer);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error appending buffer:', error);
          }
        }
      }

      handleVideoStream(base64Data) {
        const arrayBuffer = base64ToArrayBuffer(base64Data);

        if (!this.isInitialized) {
          this.init();
        }

        // Always queue the buffer
        this.queue.push(arrayBuffer);

        // Try to process the queue
        if (!this.sourceBuffer.updating) {
          this.processQueue();
        }
      }
    }

    // Create a global instance of the handler
    const videoStreamHandler = new VideoStreamHandler();

    // Listen for video stream messages
    window.addEventListener('message', (msg) => {
      if (msg.data.action === 'VIDEO_STREAM') {
        var b64data = msg.data.data;
        videoStreamHandler.handleVideoStream(b64data);
      }
    });
  </script>

It updates the src attribute of the video tag with a blob url as,
<video id="video" controls="" autoplay="" src="blob:http://localhost/603a5c88-9aed-4f18-800f-885805fc1d5b"></video>

But it returns the error of
Error appending buffer: InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer': This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source.

for the part of the code,
this.sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(arrayBuffer);

as image below,

I am not really experienced of http live streaming side of web development, can't wait to hear your suggestions to try to achieve creating video&audio from the data. Thanks.
Also implemented the solution of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102075/mediasource-error-this-sourcebuffer-has-been-removed-from-the-parent-media-sour
as below,
<video id="video" controls autoplay></video>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Convert base64 string to ArrayBuffer
    function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
      const binaryString = atob(base64);
      const bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryString.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < binaryString.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      return bytes.buffer;
    }

    var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
    var buffer;
    var queue = [];

    var video = $('#video')[0];
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function(e) {
      video.play();

      buffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"');

      buffer.addEventListener('updatestart', function(e) { console.log('updatestart: ' + mediaSource.readyState); });
      buffer.addEventListener('update', function(e) { console.log('update: ' + mediaSource.readyState); });
      buffer.addEventListener('updateend', function(e) { console.log('updateend: ' + mediaSource.readyState); });
      buffer.addEventListener('error', function(e) { console.log('error: ' + mediaSource.readyState); });
      buffer.addEventListener('abort', function(e) { console.log('abort: ' + mediaSource.readyState); });

      buffer.addEventListener('update', function() { // Note: Have tried 'updateend'
        if (queue.length > 0 && !buffer.updating) {
          buffer.appendBuffer(queue.shift());
        }
      });
    }, false);

    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function(e) { console.log('sourceopen: ' + mediaSource.readyState); });
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceended', function(e) { console.log('sourceended: ' + mediaSource.readyState); });
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceclose', function(e) { console.log('sourceclose: ' + mediaSource.readyState); });
    mediaSource.addEventListener('error', function(e) { console.log('error: ' + mediaSource.readyState); });

    // Listen for video stream messages
    window.addEventListener('message', (msg) => {
      if (msg.data.action === 'VIDEO_STREAM') {
        var b64data = base64ToArrayBuffer(msg.data.data);
        if (buffer.updating || queue.length > 0) {
          queue.push(b64data);
        } else {
          buffer.appendBuffer(b64data);
        }
      }
    });
  </script>

The same issue still persist,

So please re-open my question, I am also seeking for other resolutions other than MediaSource() if possible..

FYI, this question doesn't have anything at all to do with HLS, so I edited it for you to remove that tag.

Also, do you have to use WebSocket?  If you could just use normal HTTP GET, you could just set that URL to the video src and be done with it.

Hi @Brad thanks for interest, the data is coming partially and encoded as I mentioned so there is no such singular url which I can display the video, I somehow need to create blob: url for stream the video in my page but I couldn't still figure.

Streaming over regular HTTP works just fine... no need for Web Socket, so if you have control over the server side of whatever this is, I'd suggest changing it to just be a response to HTTP GET.  If you don't have control over the server, then your choices are really only MediaSource and the Web Codecs API.  Also, I'm not sure where you're getting this base64 from.  The Web Socket messages clearly show that the data is coming in as binary.

I am actually listening a socket stream through my browser extension and sending that data to my HTML page through postMessage, so I don't have control on the data server, in this case what approach should I follow to create the same stream in my page?

Actually, you do have control because the "server" in this case can be your extension.  You can hook an HTTP GET request, right?  If so, you could just do <video src="http://invalid.invalid/hello-extension"></video>, and then when your extension sees a GET request for that URL, write buffers to the body of the Response.

If for some reason you can't hook GET requests, then just pass raw ArrayBuffers over postMessage.  The second parameter of postMessage() is used for this.  It takes care of all the memory management and threading issues for you.
